# pl/sql column name as variable using cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I've got a table with columns like "day_1" 'day_2' 'day_3' etc 
I want to run over them using something like that:
day='day_'||to_char(i);
rec.day....

i've already learned that there's cool thing called execute emmediate, but it doesn't works for me, here's the code

```
    set SERVEROUTPUT on

declare
cursor work_days is select distinct day_1, day_2,day_3........
from workDays;
str varchar2(256);
wday varchar2(10);

begin
for rec in work_days loop
for j in 1..2 loop
str:='SELECT ''day'||to_Char(j)||''' from dual';
execute immediate str into wday;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.wday);
end loop;
end loop;
end;
```

and here's the mistake

```
PLS-00302: component 'WDAY' must be declared
```

Comment: or maybe there's another solution to do whar i want...

Comment: There are multiple errors. But the error you got is bcos, you select only days column in your cursor.. But refer a different column wday..  Rec.wday.. Always refers the cursors..not the dynamic one you created. You can form a dynamic sql. But you should know what columns you refer before hand.

Comment: Are you saying that the table `workDays` has columns `day_1`, `day_2`, etc.?  What, exactly, do you want to do with the data in that table?  What version of Oracle are you using?  You might be looking for the `unpivot` operator but it's very hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: wow, nop,sorry, it's type mistake, in real code my request is much longer so i've decided to cut it a bit for stackOverFlow, one sec,i'll correct

Comment: @JustinCave yes, I have columns with mostly identical names, from each of them i need to recieve a number and to add it to the sum, just like this: <pre>    sum:=sum+rec.day_1; sum:=sum+rec.day_2...... <code> 30 times. i don't want to do this, i want to do something like <pre> for(int i = 1; i<=30; i++) {day="day_"+i; sum+=rec.day} <code>

Answer (score 0):

First, the fact that you have a bunch of similarly named columns and that you want to aggregate the data in those columns strongly implies that your data model is incorrect.  If you had 30 rows of data rather than 30 columns, your database would be much more reasonably normalized and your queries would be much easier.

Assuming that there is a valid reason that you can't fix your data model, you really don't want to use dynamic SQL here.  You really just write a query that adds the data together

```
SELECT day_1 + day_2 + day_3 + ... + day_30 your_total
  FROM workDays
```

If you really need to keep the data model and you're really determined to complicate your life by resorting to dynamic SQL, you can do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_sum      workDays.day_1%type := 0;
  l_element  workDays.day_1%type;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..30
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'select day_' || i || ' from workDays';
    execute immediate l_sql_stmt into l_element;
    l_sum := l_sum + l_element;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that I'm assuming that there is only one row in `workDays`.  Otherwise, you'd need some sort of `WHERE` clause so that the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` can return a single row on each iteration.  Alternately, you could fetch data into collections and have a collection of sums.

Comment: unfortunatly i can't change the model, because it's my homework( and i can't make use of just sum, because there will be additional logic for each day. I've just tried to do like you've written, but there's error:     subprogram or cursor 'WORKDAYS' reference is out of scope    ((

Comment: Maybe i can somehow go over all column names and in case column name in {day_1,day_2.....} do my logic?

Comment: @Polina - Where is the syntax error coming?  In the declaration of the variables?  Or in the SQL statement?  I'm assuming that `workDays` is a table in the current schema.  If that is not accurate, you'd need to adjust the syntax.